# error handling with user input until input is correct

Tags: c, loops, error-handling, while-loop, continue

This code should first tells the user to input the numbers of triangles to check. If the user doesn't enter an integer , then the program tells the user to enter an integer again until he has done so.

Then the user has to enter a float for the triplet. 
the continue works fine here. But for the second triplet if the user doesn't enter an integer (for example he enters 2x) it goes back to the top of the while loop which is please enter the first number of the triplet. 
How can I edit my code so it doesn't go to the top of the while loop but tells the user to input the second number of the triplet again?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define request "Please enter the number of triangles to check: "
#define triplet1 "Please enter the first number of the triplet: "
#define triplet2 "Please enter the second number of the triplet: "
#define Error "[ERR] Invalid number of triangles.\n "
#define Error2 "[ERR] Invalid number for the triplet.\n"
#define UCHAR_MAX 20

int main ()
{

  int triangles = 0;
  char *end;

  for (;;)
    {
      printf ("%s", request);
      char buffer[30];
      fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);
      triangles = strtol (buffer, &end, 10);
      if (*end != '\n' || triangles < 1 || triangles > UCHAR_MAX)
    {
      printf ("%s", Error);

      continue;
    }
      break;
    }

  float triplet[3] = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
  int i = 0;
  while (i < triangles)
    {
      float tmp = 0.0;
      printf ("%s\n", triplet1);
      char buffer[30];
      fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);
      tmp = strtol (buffer, &end, 10);
      if (*end != '\n' || tmp < 1)
    {
      printf ("%s", Error2);
      continue;

    }
      triplet[0] = tmp;
     tmp = 0.0;
      printf ("%s\n", triplet2);

      fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);
      tmp = strtol (buffer, &end, 10);
      if (*end != '\n' || tmp < 1)
    {
      printf ("%s", Error2);
      continue;              // goes back to the top of the while loop 

    }

      triplet[1] = tmp;


      i++;

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's literally the definition of what a `continue` operation does. I would suggest changing title of your question so it reflects what you're having issues with in your code.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please drop the use of those macros for strings. Print the strings directly instead.

Comment: Fix your code before posting. There are way to many empty lines. Before posting, imagine that a future employer will look at your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude at our university we have to use defines for strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior for continue statement. you need to implement the inner loop for this.

If you would like to take input until the user enters correct value, please try this one:
I don't have c compiler so not able to test but hopefully, it should work. Please let me know if you see any issue.

```
while (i < triangles)
{
  float tmp = 0.0;
  char buffer[30];
  whiel(true){
    printf ("%s\n", triplet1);
  fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);
  tmp = strtol (buffer, &end, 10);
  if (*end != '\n' || tmp < 1)
    {
      printf ("%s", Error2);
      continue;
    }
    triplet[0] = tmp;
    break;
  }

 tmp = 0.0;
  while(true){
    printf ("%s\n", triplet2);
  fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin);
  tmp = strtol (buffer, &end, 10);
  if (*end != '\n' || tmp < 1)
    {
         printf ("%s", Error2);
        continue;
    }
      triplet[1] = tmp;
      i++;
       break;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The very definition of `continue` keyword says that whenever it is encountered inside a loop body, it will skip any remaining statements of the current iteration and start the loop from the very beginning, for the iteration that follows.

What you want to achieve here, in your program, is that instead of starting the loop from the beginning, it should execute a certain set of statements again for which the passing condition fails.

A possible workaround could be that you make use of the `goto` keyword here. Create a label just before the triplet2 block, and when the condition fails, call `goto` on that label.

```
label:
printf("%s\n", triplet2);
// other statements here
if(...) {
    ...
    goto label;
}
```

Still, it is just a workaround and not a good practice.

Also, it seems that you are having a block of statements which are repetitive. Try to enclose those in some function, to increase the code quality and maintainability.